# Safari Extension: change webpage styles or DOM when button is clicked

Tags: safari-extension

I'm making a Safari extension, but am not able to make any visible changes to the webpage using JS injection.

I have added a button in Extension Builder. This is global.html:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "red";
    alert('no errors!'); // this IS called
}
```

The alert IS called so the function is executed without errors. However, the body background does not become red. I have tried with different webpages. If I change the body background with Safari's Web Inspector then the page becomes red. The JS by itself is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f1tdx3za/

In Extension Builder:

Website Access: all (checked 'include secure pages')

Note that the DOM change must be linked to the button click. It should NOT be executed whenever a page loads.

Comment: In the context of the extension's global page, `document` refers to the global page, not the page in the current browser tab. Your code succeeds in coloring the global page's background red...unfortunately, the global page is invisible, and it is not the page you want to change.

To affect the page in the current browser tab (or any other tab), you have to [send a message](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) from the global page to the tab.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.